# How to get the value of the title of an URL that is passed on by cookie, using nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I would like to get the title of an URL passed on by cookie.

If I just use a normal URL, it works. (See the code below)

```
<% html=open("https://www.google.com/").read %>
<% doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html) %>
<%= doc.title %>
// I get "Google".
```

But when the url is given as a parameter via cookie, it doesn't work.

```
<% html=open(url).read %>
<% document = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html) %>
<%= document.title %>
```

I get "Net::ReadTimeout Error".
In the live shell of the error page, I typed in "url", and got "http://localhost:3000/" in return, so I know that there's no problem with getting the URL itself.
What is the problem here?

Comment: How and where do you set `url` in your second example?

Answer (score 0):

Given the errror `Net::ReadTimeout Error` the server has not responded in time. So there is no `html` for Nokogiri to parse.
Try raising the timeout limit:

`open(url, read_timeout: 2)`